# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to deserialize a subclass object from AFHTTPClient

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access, afnetworking, nscoding

I have a subclass of AFHTTPClient with NSCoding protocol methods implemented:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

  if (!self)
    return nil;

  self.isLoggedIn = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"];

  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
  [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
  [aCoder encodeBool:self.isLoggedIn forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
}
```

I also implemented the method for setting default header for the token & there I archive the client:

```
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token {
  [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", token]];

  [self setIsLoggedIn:YES];

  NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:kGCClient];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And I deserialize the client in the `- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url` implementation in my subclass:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {

  NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kGCClient];
  GCClient *client = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

  if (client)
    return self = client;

  self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

  if (!self) {
    return nil;
  }

  [self setIsLoggedIn:NO];

  return self;
}
```

The issue is that once I'm logged in, the next time I open the app it crushes on the deserialization of the client, in the `AFHTTPClient` class `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method, on the first try to decode a object & in debugger it says that the value returned is not an Objective-C object.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"baseURL"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- Use the Keychain, rather than `NSUserDefaults`, to store credentials.
- Instead of messing with `NSCoding`, simply override `-initWithBaseURL`, (making sure to call `super`, of course), and set the `Authorization` header based on the value stored in the keychain (if it exists). The `isLoggedIn` property could (and should) be defined as a derived `readonly` property, which returns `YES` when the `Authorization` header is present, and `NO` otherwise.

Comment: I did as you wrote, everything works fine now. 

The thing is that when I first saw that AFHTTPClient conforms to <NSCoding> I thought that the right way to use it is to serialize/deserialize the whole client.